# MySQL single DB accessed by two servers

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to build a website that uses MySQL DB. What I am trying to do is make my database accessed by two servers, which means when server 1 is down server 2 can access the same database and the website continues working normally. I've read about multimaster replication but it does not seem to be what I need. And what happens when using a master slave replication and the master server goes down ? How it can be restored ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Fails" might mean your database is damaged, so that's not the way out. Use replication. http://binlogtorelaylog.blogspot.com/2012/03/scaling-out-and-creating-fault-tolerant.html And try not to ask questions like that here - it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2):

I think the master slave pattern is exactly what you're looking for. The master handles all the writes and the slaves handle all the reads. If your cloud hosting with someone like Rackspace or AWS they make it very easy to set up the data replication across each mode. As for your last sub question about what happens if the master goes down, I believe it is pretty straight forward to set up fallbacks for that too. There are likely several approaches but at the most basic level I know you can set up multiple db nodes (with a fallback algorithm) just like any other instance.

A final note... If its your first time doing this I highly recommend Rackspace because their support is amazing and they make a huge effort when you start to explain all your option and help you pick the best strategy.

Ps: retreading your question, it's a little unclear what you're trying to accomplish. You mention two servers accessing one DB and  you also talk about redundant setups for multiple db instances. They're really two separate issues. The former is trivially easy because you can always just point more than one server to a db. As long as the credentials are right it will work. But the tricky part is keeping the data synched properly. If both are reading and writing the same tables things are going to bang together. That's where the master slave pattern comes into play. All the writes go through the master but anyone can read from any slave because the data gets replicated.